# Как задать исчезновение элемента при загрузке страницы (vue.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Имеется следующий код на jquery

```
window.onload = function(){
   $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
};
```

Элемент выполнил таким образом:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <div id="preloader" v-if="show">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
    </div>
</transition>
```

Javascript:

```
var preloader = new Vue({
    el: '#preloader',
    data: {
        show: true
    }
});
```

Как настроить исчезновение элемента при загрузке страницы? В документации прямого аналога fadeOut в jquery не нашел. Заранее спасибо

Comment: в нужный момент сделайте присвоение `this.show = false`

Comment: Попытался пойти таким путем:

    mounted: function () {
            this.show = false
        }

Но прелоадер исчезает быстрее, чем отрисовывается страница. Буду думать дальше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настроил следующим образом:

```
var preloader = new Vue({
    el: '#preloader',
    data: {
        show: true
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => this.show = false);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var preloader = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pageReady: false, // переменная отвечающая за показ элемента
    imgs: []          // картинками притормозим загрузку страницы
  },
  created() {         // хук создания приложения
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      this.imgs.push('https://picsum.photos/1280/960/?random&' + i);
  },
  mounted() {         // хук "монтирования" - с этого момента Vue начинает работать с документом
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
      this.pageReady = document.readyState === 'complete';
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.gallery { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; justify-content: center; align-items: flex-start; }
.gallery > img { flex 0 0 auto; width: 100px; margin: 4px; }

#loading {
  position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;
  width: 250px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font: 20px/80px sans-serif; text-align: center;
  transition: transform 1.2s linear, opacity 0.4s linear 0.1s;
  background: #fff; box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #0004; }

/* конечное состояние перехода loading-fade */
.loading-fade-leave-to { transform: translate(-50%, -300%) scale(0.7) !important; opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img v-for="(url, i) of imgs" :src="url">
  </div>
  <transition name="loading-fade">
    <div id="loading" v-if="!pageReady">Загрузка...</div>
  </transition>
</div>
```